Circular Import During `dictConfig` in Python Logging
I have a custom logger with the below structure, it uses dictConfig to read the default.json file for the logger. It works fine, but when I wanted to nest under a project root, I got an error while importing it. Any reason why that might happen? I double checked the path and it see to be correct.
Initial Structure
tealogger/
  - configuration/
    - default.json
  - __init__.py
  - formatter.py
  - ...

Nested Structure
projectroot/
  - tealogger/
    - configuration/
      - default.json
    - __init__.py
    - formatter.py
    - ...

Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/substance3d_scene_automation_110_m_1089/lib/python3.11/logging/config.py", line 400, in resolve
    found = getattr(found, frag)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: cannot access submodule 'tealogg' of module 'projectroot' (most likely due to a circular import)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/substance3d_scene_automation_110_m_1089/lib/python3.11/logging/config.py", line 552, in configure
    formatters[name] = self.configure_formatter(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/python/substance3d_scene_automation_110_m_1089/lib/python3.11/logging/config.py", line 664, in configure_formatter
    result = self.configure_custom(config)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/python/substance3d_scene_automation_110_m_1089/lib/python3.11/logging/config.py", line 479, in configure_custom
    c = self.resolve(c)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/python/substance3d_scene_automation_110_m_1089/lib/python3.11/logging/config.py", line 403, in resolve
    found = getattr(found, frag)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: cannot access submodule 'tealogg' of module 'projectroot' (most likely due to a circular import)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/yk/Desktop/Project/Repository/Adobe/3DIQE/projectroot/projectroot/tealogger/__init__.py", line 128, in <module>
    tealogger = TeaLogger(
             ^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/yk/Desktop/Project/Repository/Adobe/3DIQE/projectroot/projectroot/tealogger/__init__.py", line 100, in __new__
    logging.config.dictConfig(DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION)
  File "/opt/python/substance3d_scene_automation_110_m_1089/lib/python3.11/logging/config.py", line 823, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/opt/python/substance3d_scene_automation_110_m_1089/lib/python3.11/logging/config.py", line 555, in configure
    raise ValueError('Unable to configure '
ValueError: Unable to configure formatter 'color'

The shorten version of the code is below, full version can be found committed to GitHub. The result I got can be replicated with the develop-nest branch. I simply just started a Python shell, and ran from projectroot import tealogger.
projectroot/tealogger/__init__.py
import json
import logging
import logging.config
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Union


# Log Level
CRITICAL = logging.CRITICAL
FATAL = logging.FATAL
ERROR = logging.ERROR
WARNING = logging.WARNING
WARN = logging.WARN
INFO = logging.INFO
DEBUG = logging.DEBUG
NOTSET = logging.NOTSET


# Default
DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION = None
CURRENT_MODULE_PATH = Path(__file__).parent.expanduser().resolve()
with open(
    CURRENT_MODULE_PATH / 'configuration' / 'default.json',
    mode='r',
    encoding='utf-8'
) as file:
    DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION = json.load(file)


class TeaLogger(logging.Logger):
    def __new__(cls, name: Union[str, None] = None, level: Union[int, str] = NOTSET, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get('dictConfig'):
            # Dictionary
            logging.config.dictConfig(kwargs.get('dictConfig'))
        elif kwargs.get('fileConfig'):
            # File
            ...
        else:
            # Default

            if 'loggers' not in DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION:
                DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION['loggers'] = {}
            if name not in DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION['loggers']:
                # Configure new logger with default configuration
                DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION['loggers'][name] = {
                    'propagate': kwargs.get('propagate', False),
                    'handlers': kwargs.get('handler_list', ['default'])
                }

                # configuration['loggers'][name]['handlers'] = kwargs.get('handler_list')

                # NOTE: Override only individual configuration!
                # Overriding the entire configuration will cause this child
                # logger to inherit any missing configuration from the root
                # logger. (Even if the configuration was set previously.)
                DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION['loggers'][name]['level'] = logging.getLevelName(level)
                # configuration['loggers'][name]['level'] = level

            logging.config.dictConfig(DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION)

        # Get (Create) the Logger
        tea = logging.getLogger(name)

        return tea

    def __init__(self, name: str, level: Union[int, str] = NOTSET) -> None:
        super().__init__(self, name=name, level=level)


tea = TeaLogger(name=__name__, level=WARNING)

def set_level(level: Union[int, str] = NOTSET):
    tea.setLevel(level)

def log(level: Union[int, str], message: str, *args, **kwargs):
    if isinstance(level, str):
        level = logging.getLevelName(level)
    tea.log(level=level, msg=message, *args, **kwargs)


def debug(message: str, *args, **kwargs):
    tea.debug(message, *args, **kwargs)

...

projectroot/tealogger/configuration/default.json
{
    "version": 1,
    "formatters": {
        "default": {
            "format": "[%(levelname)s %(name)s %(asctime)s] %(message)s",
            "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"
        },
        "short": {
            "format": "[%(levelname)-.1s %(asctime)s] %(message)s",
            "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"
        },
        "color": {
            "()": "projectroot.tealogger.formatter.ColorFormatter",
            "record_format": "[%(levelname)s %(name)s %(asctime)s] %(message)s",
            "date_format": "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"
        }
    },
    "filters": {
        "stdout": {
            "()" : "projectroot.tealogger.filter.StandardOutFilter"
        }
    },
    "handlers": {
        "default": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "formatter": "default",
            "filters": [],
            "stream": "ext://sys.stdout"
        },
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "formatter": "color",
            "filters": [],
            "stream": "ext://sys.stdout"
        },
        "stdout": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "formatter": "color",
            "filters": [
                "stdout"
            ],
            "stream": "ext://sys.stdout"
        },
        "stderr": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "level": "ERROR",
            "formatter": "color",
            "filters": [],
            "stream": "ext://sys.stderr"
        }
    },
    "loggers": {
        "base": {
            "level": "WARNING",
            "propagate": false,
            "filters": [],
            "handlers": [
                "stderr",
                "stdout"
            ]
        },
        "tealogger": {
            "level": "WARNING",
            "propagate": false,
            "filters": [],
            "handlers": [
                "console"
            ]
        },
        "tealogger.test.conftest": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "propagate": false,
            "filters": [],
            "handlers": [
                "stderr",
                "stdout"
            ]
        }
    },
    "root": {
        "level": "WARNING",
        "filters": [],
        "handlers": [
            "default"
        ]
    },
    "incremental": false,
    "disable_existing_loggers": false
}

projectroot/tealogger/formatter.py
import logging
from typing import Union


ESC = '\x1b['

_COLOR_CODE = {
    # Reset
    'RESET': f'{ESC}0m',
    # Foreground
    'FOREGROUND_BLACK': f'{ESC}30m',
    ...
}

_LEVEL_COLOR_CODE = {
    'NOTSET': _COLOR_CODE['RESET'],
    'DEBUG': _COLOR_CODE['FOREGROUND_CYAN'],
    'INFO': _COLOR_CODE['FOREGROUND_GREEN'],
    'WARNING': _COLOR_CODE['FOREGROUND_YELLOW'],
    'SUCCESS': _COLOR_CODE['FOREGROUND_GREEN'],
    'ERROR': _COLOR_CODE['FOREGROUND_RED'],
    'CRITICAL': f"{_COLOR_CODE['FOREGROUND_RED']}{_COLOR_CODE['BACKGROUND_WHITE']}",
}

class ColorFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def __init__(self, record_format: Union[str, None] = None, date_format: Union[str, None] = None) -> None:
        super().__init__(fmt=record_format, datefmt=date_format)

        self._level_format = {
            logging.DEBUG: (
                f"{_LEVEL_COLOR_CODE['DEBUG']}"
                f"{record_format}"
                f"{_LEVEL_COLOR_CODE['NOTSET']}"
            ),
            logging.INFO: (
                f"{_LEVEL_COLOR_CODE['INFO']}"
                f"{record_format}"
                f"{_LEVEL_COLOR_CODE['NOTSET']}"
            ),
            ...
        }

        self._date_format = date_format

    def format(
        self,
        record: logging.LogRecord
    ) -> str:
        ...



Please post a [mre]. Someone more familiar with the library might see the problem, but for me, I'd need to see the code to get it.

thanks @wjandrea, added sample code with steps to replicate

Put the [mcve] itself, not a link to it, in the question.

@YTKme An MRE needs to be included in the question as text and needs to be minimal
